# only 3 thread to access spring service layer at a time while keeping other request in buffer

Tags: spring, rest, email

We have an utility for sending an email to customers. Currently we are using outlook for sending an emails, But once we send multiple email at a time we get the following error msg.

```
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 432 4.3.2 STOREDRV.ClientSubmit; sender thread limit exceeded
```

After debugging its found that we can't send 3 mails at a time. So thought another approach to send msgs by queuing the request and process the 3 request at a time while keeping other in buffer.

Note: Don't want to use any msq queuing service (like rabbitMQ etc)

Your suggests/inputs will be really helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Office SMTP (I guess from the error message), there is a limit on concurrent connection.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/send-emails/smtp-submission-improvements)

> Under the new limit, up to three concurrent connections are allowed to send email messages at the same time.

Comment: What approach should i used to overcome on the issue. Is it possible to create a queue for all the request and processed the request sequentially?

Comment: Yes you can use concurrent queue, rate limiters or if it is an option, use another smtp (if memory serves me right, google for example let you use 20).